# s5 flex menu not working on k2 gallery page (joomla)

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-k2

The menu dropdown does not work on the gallery page. Please check the below two links for example:-
http://www.midvaleapartments.com/
http://www.midvaleapartments.com/gallery

The menu seems to work fine on all the pages except the gallery page. May be some js is comflicting. I tried  jQuery.noConflict(); but it does not work. Can anyone provide the solution for the above problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have included jQuery library 3 times
2. jQuery library conflicts with mootools

Exclude old jQuery version libraries and add jQuery.noConflict() just after it is included.

To use jQuery's sign `$` in code use:

```
// Runs after document is loaded
jQuery(function($) {
    // Your code here
});
```

or

```
(function($) {
    // Your code here
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also ensure that jQuery is only included once by replacing the jQuery include code for the extenson that use it, with the following.

```
if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
   JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
   $document =& JFactory::getDocument();
   $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "path/to/jquery/file/jquery-1.8.2.js");
}
```

Basically, this code sarch for an existing jquery library that's being included and if one isn't already, it includes one. You will have to change the path according to the location of the file.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But I found another solution for this. Add the below code just after you load the jquery file $document->addScriptDeclaration('jQuery.noConflict()');